# Bootstrap popover floats away when the user scrolls down and clicks on the element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, popover

I use bootstrap popover for an SVG element. Everything is fine, except the time when the user scrolls down a little bit and wants to see the popover by clicking. The popover floats away shows away form the element

This is my SVG element:

```
<div id="svg-container">
    <svg>
        <g id="B2" class="blockgroup">
            <path id="B2_Block" class="block" d="M195.4,128.9c-28,18.2-51.9,42.2-70.1,70.2l33.3,19.3c14.8-22.6,34-42,56.5-57L195.4,128.9z"/>
            <text id="B2_Text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 166.0186 177.8625)" class="text">B2</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#svg-container {
    width:800px;
    margin:150px auto 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

and the following is the popover options:

```
$('.blockgroup').on('click', function(e){

    var _this = $(this);

    $(_this).addClass('selected').promise().done(function() {
        $(_this).popover('show');
    });

}).popover({
    html: true,
    animation: true,
    container:'body',
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'top',
    content: function(){
       return '<div class="popover-box">' +
                  '<span>Block</span>' +
                  '<h3>' + $(this).attr('data-block-label') + '</h3>' +
                  '<a href="#" class="view-seats" data-block-id="' + this.id + '">View Seats</a>' +
              '</div>';
    }

});
```

This is the desired result:

[image]

And this is just when user scrolls down and then clicks on the path to see the popover (**the popover does not float away when it is shown and the user scrolls down (it is OK)**):

[image]

I tried to change the `container` option to `'#svg-container'` or to the element's ID by `'#' + $(this).attr('id')`, but again it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a working snippet? Seems like a CSS issue